# How to return '+' directly from lexer(without token)

Tags: c, parsing, lexer

Currently I am doing something like

```
"+" return TADD;
```

in my .l file to return token TADD.I want to know if there is a way I can return '+' directly so that I don't have to add a token for every operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this yacc/lex?  If so, then you can just

```
"+" return '+';
```

Comment: tanx..I had set SSTYPE to double.Can you please tell me how can I return matching pattern,like from '+' | '-' | '*' return '+'?

Comment: Actually has nothing to do with YYSTYPE (token types are always ints), but is otherwise correct

Answer (score 0):

Its common to have a lex rule something like:

```
[+*/(){}|&^%]|"["|"]"|"-"      return *yytext;
```

which matches a range of single characters and returns the character as a token